# Spring Boot Cloud Config Server and Client Actuator endpoints not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config

I am currently working on setup some spring boot application in which one will be the config-server and others will be the client.
For example:

1. config-server
2. resource-server
3. web-ui(Also a boot application with spring secuirty and apache tiles)

The problem I am facing that in web-ui the actuator endpoints are not working they give 401 error.

The following code id of the spring security configuration in web-ui

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
            .disable();
            http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("**/actuator/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard").loginProcessingUrl("/processLogin")
            .and()
            .logout().logoutUrl("/logoutProcessUrl").logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/login?error")
            .and().httpBasic();
        http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/login?session");
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler customAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    }}
```

Code of the spring configuraion

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("in.gov.indianrail.hrms.*")
public class SpringConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions(new String[]{"/WEB-INF/views/tiles/hrms-tiles.xml"});
        tilesConfigurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
        return tilesConfigurer;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        TilesViewResolver viewResolver = new TilesViewResolver();
        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
    }

    @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        interceptor.setParamName("lang");
        return interceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    public CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        localeResolver.setCookieName("irhrms-locale-cookie");
        localeResolver.setCookieMaxAge(3600);
        return localeResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
        return multipartResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

Project bootstrap.properties file I have added the following

```
spring.application.name=web-server
spring.jmx.default-domain=web-server
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:20000/config-server
#spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8080/config-server/
management.security.enable=false
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.context-path=/actuator
endpoints.actuator.enabled=true
endpoints.logfile.enabled=true
```

And the error it returns when I hit the actuator endpoints
like for refresh /actuator/refresh POST request I got the following error

```
    org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:378)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:318)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:350)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:964)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl.handle(AccessDeniedHandlerImpl.java:73)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
09-10-2018 09:31:27  [ERROR] [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet]] ,Line No:182 - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'timestamp' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.ui.ModelMap' - maybe not public or not valid?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:217) ~[spring-expression-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104) ~[spring-expression-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:91) ~[spring-expression-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:111) ~[spring-expression-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:265) ~[spring-expression-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$ExpressionResolver.resolvePlaceholder(ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.java:320) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.NonRecursivePropertyPlaceholderHelper$NonRecursivePlaceholderResolver.resolvePlaceholder(NonRecursivePropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:56) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:145) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.NonRecursivePropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(NonRecursivePropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:38) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView.render(ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.java:248) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl.handle(AccessDeniedHandlerImpl.java:73) [spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:155) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:123) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_77]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_77]
09-10-2018 09:31:27  [ERROR] [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet]] ,Line No:182 - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'timestamp' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.ui.ModelMap' - maybe not public or not valid?] with root cause
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'timestamp' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.ui.ModelMap' - maybe not public or not valid?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:217) ~[spring-expression-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
```

And if I make a GET request it returns

```
{
"timestamp": 1539057951282,
"status": 401,
"error": "Unauthorized",
"message": "Unauthorized",
"path": "/actuator/refresh"
}
```

So can anyone help where I am getting it wrong.

Comment: can you also update your controller code.How u manage error ?

Comment: I have create a @ControllerAdvice to handle exceptions

Comment: You have done a common mistake in @controlleradvice .Can you tell that have you bind "/error" as setview name .Please update code of that class in the question.

Comment: So can you suggest what should I update in that controller cause I have to show error pages as well as I need to hit the actuator endpoints
`@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionController {
@ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ModelAndView handleError404(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e) {
        LOGGER.info("Exception Error 404");
        return new ModelAndView("error");
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    private static final String DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW = "error";
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView defaultErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("exception", e);
        mav.addObject("url", request.getRequestURI());
        mav.setViewName(DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW);
        return mav;
    }
}
```

Replace your exceptional handler.
Actually the view resolver would find the template named error.html in the template folder, if the view resolver can not find one it will use the default one, in which the timestamp is needed in models.

Hope this may work otherwise try also another option by adding below lines to your application.properties.

> server.error.whitelabel.enabled = false

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this not the solution that I needed. Basically, I had already handle the exception but the problem is that I am not able to hit the actuator endpoints. As I have already mention when I tried to hit the actuator refresh end point then I get error on POST or on GET request.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding could you please append these properties in your application.properties.                                    endpoints.cors.allowed-origins = your url
endpoints.cors.allowed-methods = GET,POST